# Possible Race Condition in Serial read/write Code

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port, python-multithreading

I am writing python code that reads and writes to a serial device. The device is basically an Arduino Mega running the [Marlin](https://github.com/ErikZalm/Marlin) 3D printer firmware.

My python code is sending a series of GCode commands (ASCII strings terminated by newlines, including checksums and line numbers). Marlin responds to each successfully received line with an "ok\n". Marlin only has a limited line buffer size so if it is full Marlin will hold off on sending the "ok\n" response until space is freed up.

If the checksum fails then Marlin requests the line to be sent again with a "Resend: 143\n" response. Another possible response is "ok T:{temp value}\n" if the current temperature is requested.

My code uses three threads. The main thread, a read thread and a write thread. Here is a stripped down version of the code:

```
class Printer:

    def connect(self):
        self.s = serial.Serial(self.port, self.baudrate, timeout=3)
        self.ok_received.set()

    def _start_print_thread(self):
        self.print_thread = Thread(target=self._empty_buffer, name='Print')
        self.print_thread.setDaemon(True)
        self.print_thread.start()

    def _start_read_thread(self):
        self.read_thread = Thread(target=self._continous_read, name='Read')
        self.read_thread.setDaemon(True)
        self.read_thread.start()

    def _empty_buffer(self):
        while not self.stop_printing:
            if self.current_line_idx < len(self.buffer):
                while not self.ok_received.is_set() and not self.stop_printing:
                    logger.debug('waiting on ok_received')
                    self.ok_received.wait(2)
                line = self._next_line()
                self.s.write(line)
                self.current_line_idx += 1
                self.ok_received.clear()
            else:
                break

    def _continous_read(self):
        while not self.stop_reading:
            if self.s is not None:
                line = self.s.readline()
                if line == 'ok\n':
                    self.ok_received.set()
                    continue  # if we got an OK then we need to do nothing else.
                if 'Resend:' in line:  # example line: "Resend: 143"
                    self.current_line_idx = int(line.split()[1]) - 1
                if line:  # if we received _anything_ then set the flag
                    self.ok_received.set()
            else:  # if no printer is attached, wait 10ms to check again.
                sleep(0.01)
```

In the above code, `self.ok_received` is a `threading.Event`. This *mostly* works ok. Once every couple of hours however it gets stuck in the `while not self.ok_received.is_set() and not self.stop_printing:` loop inside of `_empty_buffer()`. This kills the print by locking up the machine.

When stuck inside the loop, I can get the print to continue by sending any command manually. This allows the read thread to set the `ok_recieved` flag.

Since Marlin does not respond with checksums, I guess it is possible the "ok\n" gets garbled. The third if statement in the read thread is supposed to handle this by setting the flag if *anything* is received from Marlin.

So my question is: Do I have a possible race condition somewhere? Before I add locks all over the place or combine the two threads into one I would really like to understand how this is failing. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: CPython is single threaded only in that it executes one python instruction at a time. Things you care about, like Serial port I/O can and will happen in parallel as they don't involve waiting on a python instruction.

Comment: Does that mean I should put a lock around the reading and writing to the serial port?

Comment: @dano I think you found it, if you want to submit your response as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @jminardi Sure, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the read thread could get some data in the window where the write thread has broken out of the `is_set` loop, but has not yet called `self.ok_received.clear()`. So, the read thread ends up calling `self.ok_received.set()` while the write thread is still processing the previous line, and then the write thread unknowingly calls `clear()` once its done processing the previous message, and never knows that another line should be written.

```
def _empty_buffer(self):
    while not self.stop_printing:
        if self.current_line_idx < len(self.buffer):
            while not self.ok_received.is_set() and not self.stop_printing:
                logger.debug('waiting on ok_received')
                self.ok_received.wait(2)
            # START OF RACE WINDOW
            line = self._next_line()
            self.s.write(line)
            self.current_line_idx += 1
            # END OF RACE WINDOW
            self.ok_received.clear()
        else:
            break
```

A `Queue` might be a good way to handle this - you want to write one line in the write thread every time the read thread receives a line. If you replaced `self.ok_received.set()` with `self.recv_queue.put("line")`, then the write thread could just write one line every time it pulls something from the `Queue`:

```
def _empty_buffer(self):
    while not self.stop_printing:
        if self.current_line_idx < len(self.buffer):
            while not self.stop_printing:
                logger.debug('waiting on ok_received')
                try:
                     val = self.recv_queue.get(timeout=2)
                except Queue.Empty:
                    pass
                else:
                    break
            line = self._next_line()
            self.s.write(line)
            self.current_line_idx += 1
        else:
            break
```

You could also shrink the window to the point you probably won't hit it in practice by moving the call to `self.ok_received.clear()` up immediately after exiting the inner `while` loop, but technically there will still be a race.

Comment: @jminardi, do you mind sharing your code?
it looks interesting

Comment: @embedded You can use this code in my python library `mecode`. The object in question can be found here: https://github.com/jminardi/mecode/blob/master/mecode/printer.py